# When I query for TXT records, how can I tell that I've resolved all of them if there are multiple?

Tags: domain-name-system, txt-record

I'm not familiar with the mechanism by which TXT records are communicated back to the client. Does it just wait until timeout receiving records? Or does the server somehow indicate the the client the number of records?

Comment: Pablo is correct. While this is more advanced reading, you may want to look more closely at [the packet structure](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/dns.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a client sends a query to a DNS server the server answers telling the client how many resource records are included (really gives RR answers, authority and additional RRs) so the client can process the answer.

So in short, the protocol defines the answers there is no wait as the response format is properly defined. E.g if you run `dig -t txt gmail.com` you will get the (only) TXT record back immediately.